# cuda: effective Bandwidth in the sdk example of Reduction

Tags: cuda, bandwidth

in the reduction.pdf ,it introduces the reduction method through 7 steps ,there are 16777216 elements,in the 1th step,the effective bandwidth is 2.083 GB/S,how 2.083GB/S come out? and how the 2th step bandwidth 4.854GB/s come out?

Answer (score 2):

The bandwidth figures are calculated using the number of **bytes** in the reduction input data divided by the execution time (note there are 2^22 integers = 16777216 bytes). The calculation is clearly shown on page 10 of the pdf that ships in the SDK in `reduction/doc`.

Comment: I saw the 2.083GB/s ,but how calculate it? because i must learn to calculate the other programs, so I must know how it comes out?

Comment: 16777216 bytes / 8.054 milliseconds = 2083091135 bytes per second = 2.083 Gb/s.

Comment: you have to know the size of each element first, then multiply it with the number of elements to get the size of all data in 'bytes'. finally divide it by the time, then you get the bandwidth in ((G)bytes/sec).